# Post Request with axios giving error 400. u

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, mern

so i am new to building applications and have been building an submit form, but my post request gives me an Error 400. i know my database is connected because my GET requests work fine and i know my API is somewhat functional because insomnia does POST requests fine. this is my code for the apply.js page. in the console, the state changes shows up, so i think the information is being passed fine. i feel like it must be my post request somewhere being poorly done.

```
function Apply() {
    const [applicant, setApplicant] = useState("");
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
    const [loanAmount, setLoanAmount] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = ({target})=> {
    if(target.name === "username") setApplicant(target.value);
    else if(target.name === "address") setAddress(target.value);
    else if(target.name === "loanAmount") setLoanAmount(target.value);
    else console.error("error changing Applicant");
  }
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault() 
    console.log(applicant, loanAmount, address);

    axios
    .post('http://localhost:5000/users/add',{applicant, loanAmount, address}) 
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log("Error of type: " + err))
```

i feel like i'm doing something really stupid or just syntactically silly, but here is the user.model,js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, trim: true, minlength: 3},
    loanrequest: {type: Number, required: true, trim: true},
    address: {type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    email: {type: String, required: false, trim: true}
});

let users = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = users;
```

and this is my route that uses the model it's in Users.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    User.find(req.params.id)
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.post('/add', (req, res) => {

    const username= req.body.username;
    const loanrequest= Number(req.body.loanrequest);
    const address= req.body.address;
    const email = req.body.address;
    const newUser = new User ({
        username,
        loanrequest,
        address,
        email
     });

        newUser.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Application Added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
    });

module.exports = router;
```

i'm sorry if this post is super long. i've spent about 2 days just trying to figure out what i've been doing wrong. thanks for any help!

Comment: did the below answer work for you?

Comment: it didn't. when i changed the route, it gave me a 404 error instead of 400.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried instead of this code

```
const username= req.body.username;
const loanrequest= Number(req.body.loanrequest);
const address= req.body.address;
const email = req.body.address;
const newUser = new User({
    username,
    loanrequest,
    address,
    email
 });
```

the code below, I don't think you can create a new document like that because in the above case the schema will take an object as following {1: ..., 2: ...} instead of the desired properties (username, email, etc...)

```
const userData = {
    username: req.body.username,
    loanrequest: Number(req.body.loanrequest),
    address: req.body.address,
    email: req.body.address
}
const newUser = new User(userData);
```

Comment: i tried using this code instead, but it still gives me the same error 400. I'm not really sure why, considering when i use insomnia to test out the API, it seems to work.

Comment: Hmm... It could be the format of the request body or something like that, that is pretty strange